# How to make logo over lay over 3 navbar using?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using 3 navbar's one below the other and the first navbar is with link in the right.
My second navbar has logo towards right, and links towards left.

But I see that my logo doesn't come like the way I want. The second navbar takes the height of the logo.

What am I missing?

Comment: Add your code or create a jsfiddle so we can help you with this. And welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a [**demo bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/4DlxX82jxU) demonstrating what I think youu're looking for.

It has 3 navbars, with a logo in the second, overlapping the third navbar.

Comment: @TED...yes this is what I'm trying to do but my logo should overlap both anyways thank you for your greeting and the solution...I think I can get it done from here...